# DB Error: connect failed (code 24)

Tags: wordpress, database, error

Anyone have any idea how I can fix this?
Just done install and CiviCRM did not load (all OK on wizard) then nothing.
Removed CiviCRM from the WordPress install and uploaded again (also removed database) but error below appeared.

Have I missed something?

Initialization Error

Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => simpleHandler
        )

```
[code] => -24
[message] => DB Error: connect failed
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] =>  [nativecode=php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known]
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] =>  [nativecode=php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known]
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: connect failed" code=-24 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix="" info=" [nativecode=php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known]"]
```

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to recreate your civicrm.settings.php file - or at least check the DB settings in there.

It's typically created upon install and located in wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php

Comment: Where is this located?

Comment: Updated answer :)

Comment: And if its not there... :(

Comment: Then run the installer again :) Follow the instructions on installing CiviCRM on WordPress

Comment: If it's Civi 4.7.n on WP single instance, then civicrm.settings.php will be in `wp-content/uploads/civicrm`.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianWach that was ideal and fixed the issue!